# How does the Vaccinator work?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-medic

How exactly does it work? The description states that by using "special fire" it change resist types.  What are these resist types?

How exactly does its ubercharge work?  Compared with the other 3 medic weapons, does it heal slower or faster?

How many ubers do you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, here are the full stats:

> The Vaccinator
>
> Special-Attack:
>
> Cycle through resist types. While healing, provides you and your target with a constant 10% resistant to the selected damage type.
>
> - +50% ubercharge rate
> - -66% overheal build rate
> - Ubercharge provides 75% resistance to a selected damage type. You are healed for 25% of the matched incoming damage on your heal target.

You can switch the type of resistance the target has by pressing the reload key (default: <kbd>R</kbd>). Resistance types are bullet damage, explosive damage, and fire damage.

Ubers are divided into 4 sections, giving you 4 **SEPERATE** ubers.  Each "uber" takes roughly 20 seconds to charge.  You can control when you want to use your ubers, so let's say you use the first two ubers, then save the rest for later.

The uber itself grants **75%** resistance, as mentioned, to a specific type.  It is a resistance to **ONE** type, **not MULTIPLE** types.  Also worth mentioning that it is **not an uber**, just a resistance to a certain damage type.  Another thing as well is that while in uber, you cannot change your resistance type.

Comment: It also heals at the same rate as the Medigun and Kritz, and only overheals more slowly.

Answer (score 1):

In addendum to Retrosaur's answer: Resist types are associated with damage types: fire, bullet, melee, falling, environmental, etc.  I'm not sure which damage types are covered by The Vaccinator as of yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just bullet, fire, and explosive; the same resistance types available in MvM.

Comment: Sure melee isn't in there, too? There's four resistance types covered by the Vaccinator.

Comment: Yes, it cycles between bullet, explosive, and fire, in that order.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  The ubers are technically resistance type-independent.  You just toggle which of the resistances the uber will use.