# When should I use the Vaccinator?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-medic

When would I want to use the vaccinator, specifically over the default medigun?

The vaccinator has an almost negligible 10% resistance to one damage type during regular usage, which to me does not outweigh the slower overheal build.

During uber, you are only mostly resistant to one damage type, compared to completely immune to all damage types.

Another question already asked reveals the [mechanics of the vaccinator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96761/5370).

When should I be switching to the Vaccinator? When is it tactically a better choice? I usually run medigun or kritz, and usually play in pubs.

Comment: IMO, I prefer any of the other Mediguns over the Vaccinator (mainly Quick Fix for the super fast heal rate). All Mediguns are good at different times. At one moment, the Kritzkreig is the best option, but at other, the normal is, ect. ect. It is all based upon opinion and how good you can use the medigun.

Comment: I don't have the time to write a full answer, but the main difference here is that you can deploy your mini-uber almost immediately after spawning.

Comment: If you play in pubs, I'd recommend not using it. The vaccinator is a lot more difficult to use effectively for both parties and needs better communication than you're likely to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the enemy team has a lot of one damage type, such as a lot of Soldiers/Demos or a lot of Scouts/Heavies/Engineers, the Vaccinator's quick-charging mini-übers can provide a similar degree of protection more often than a slow-building Über or Megaheal. This is especially true if they have Kritz; all four of a Vaccinator's charges should be able to completely counter a kritzed opponent unwilling or unable to switch to a differently-damaging weapon.

That said, the Vaccinator is not designed for concentrated pushes. It's more effective for just keeping the team alive and letting their aliveness move the team forwards. In that sense you can't really use it the same way as the others and expect it to do well. This is especially true in pubs, as players probably don't feel confident enough with a mini-über to get in there like they would if they were invulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use it on payload when pushing the cart since it allows for faster healing of multiple teammates.

A normal uber would also stop me and my target from pushing the cart.

Naturally, I resort to the default if progress is stalled by a sentry.